# Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile pepk.jar

Tags: android, keystore

when i generate xx.zip to uploads goole play console with the blow code

it promopt  Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile pepk.jar

the pepk.jar from gooleplay console, so i do not know how to slove it. i google it but there is no method to solve it